# Why don't strings have a Planck mass of vibrational energy?

Tags: string-theory, dimensional-analysis, mass-energy, physical-constants

It is claimed that strings have a length $l_S$ within an order of magnitude of the Planck length $l_{Pl}=10^{-35}$ m.

If they oscillate at the speed of light, $c=10^8$ m/s, then their natural frequency $f_S$ is

$$f_S\sim \frac{c}{l_S} \sim 10^{43}\mbox{ Hz}.$$

Therefore their vibrational energy $E_S=hf_S$, where the Planck constant $h=10^{-34}$ J Hz$^{-1}$, is given by

$$E_S=hf=10^9\mbox{ J}.$$

The equivalent mass $M_S=E_S/c^2$ is given by

$$M_S=10^{-7}\mbox{ kg}=M_{Pl}.$$

If strings are a Planck length in size why don't they have a Planck mass worth of vibrational energy?

Surely the length of a string $l_S$ should be given by

$$l_S \sim \frac{h}{M_S c}$$

where $M_S$ is the equivalent mass provided by the vibrational energy $E_S=M_S c^2$ ?

Thus if a string represents an electron at rest with mass $10^{-30}$ kg then its length $l_S$ should be given by

$$l_S\sim\frac{10^{-34}}{10^{-30}10^8}\sim 10^{-12}\mbox{ m},$$

which is the Compton wavelength of an electron.

If the electron is moving with velocity $v$ then its string length $l_S$ is given by

$$l_S \sim \frac{h}{\gamma_v M_S c},$$

where $\gamma_v=(1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Vibrating strings *do* have a Planck-scale mass. In string phenomenology, standard model particles correspond to different kinds of nonvibrating massless string (some of which then acquire their small masses via a stringy Higgs mechanism).

Comment: Interesting - I had heard that the standard model particles are fundamentally massless. I didn’t realize that this implies that their corresponding strings are not vibrating. I suppose that if they move at the velocity of light then their time has stopped relative to an inertial frame.